Tibco EMS JMS fault tolerance not working with Spring Boot
I can make a connection to the EMS queue from Spring, and it's working fine with this configuration:

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class TibcoJmsConfiguration {

    public static final String SUN_AND_IBM_JSSE_SUPPORT = "j2se-default";

    private final ParameterService parameterService;

    private final ServerConfig serverConfig;

    public TibcoJmsConfiguration(ParameterService parameterService, ServerConfig serverConfig) {
        this.parameterService = parameterService;
        this.serverConfig = serverConfig;
    }

    //based on TibcoJmsInitialContext.class 
    @Bean(name = "tibJmsConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException, JMSException {

        // custom fault-tolerant system because url divided by comma not working:
        // serverUrl = tcp://server0:7222,tcp://server1:7344
        // workaround: use db value + restart jvm
        String emsQueueUrl = parameterService.getEmsQueueUrl();
        return getTibjmsConnectionFactory(emsQueueUrl);

    }

    @NotNull
    private TibjmsConnectionFactory getTibjmsConnectionFactory(String emsQueueUrl) {
        final TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory(emsQueueUrl);

        // https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.6.0/doc/html/GUID-CE5017DD-EF33-417A-AE0F-59DA05FA7BC7.html
        connectionFactory.setConnAttemptCount(5);
        connectionFactory.setConnAttemptDelay(1000);
        connectionFactory.setConnAttemptTimeout(1000);

        connectionFactory.setUserName(serverConfig.getConfigValue(CRM_USER));
        connectionFactory.setUserPassword(serverConfig.getConfigValue(CRM_PWD));
        connectionFactory.setSSLIdentity(serverConfig.getConfigValue(CRM_SSL_IDENTITY));
        connectionFactory.setSSLPassword(serverConfig.getConfigValue(CRM_SSL_PASSWORD));
        connectionFactory.setSSLDebugTrace(serverConfig.getConfigBoolean(CRM_DEBUG));
        connectionFactory.setSSLTrace(serverConfig.getConfigBoolean(CRM_TRACE));
        connectionFactory.setSSLTrustedCertificate(serverConfig.getConfigValue(CRM_SSL_TRUSTED));
        connectionFactory.setSSLEnableVerifyHost(false);
        connectionFactory.setSSLVendor(SUN_AND_IBM_JSSE_SUPPORT);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

  
    @Bean
    public BackOff getFixedBackOff(){
        //block attempt connection 
        FixedBackOff backOff = new FixedBackOff();
        backOff.setMaxAttempts(5);
        backOff.setInterval(5000);
        return backOff;
    }



    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("tibJmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactor) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactor);
        factory.setBackOff(getFaultTolerantBackOff());
        return factory;
    }


    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(String url) {
        return getTibjmsConnectionFactory(url);
    }
}

Where emsQueueUrl is like ssl://ms-server-1:1234,ssl://ms-server-2:1234.
At the start it even detects that if ms-server-1 is down to switch to ms-server-2.
And I have a class with @JmsListener which receives messages:
@Component
public class CrmEventReceiver {
  
    private final CrmEventService crmEventService;
    private final ServerConfig serverConfig;
    private final ParameterService parameterService;


    public CrmEventReceiver(CrmEventService crmEventService, ServerConfig serverConfig, ParameterService parameterService) {
        this.crmEventService = crmEventService;
        this.serverConfig = serverConfig;
        this.parameterService = parameterService;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "AGPI.QL.MY_EVENT_INPUT")
    public void receiveMessage(Object messageInput) {
       try {
                TextMessage message = (TextMessage) messageInput;
                notNull(message, "[CRM_EVENT] TibcoJMSTextMessage - Could not receive message");
               lEvent(message.getText());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                LOGGER.error("[CRM_EVENT] TibcoJMSTextMessage - Could not convert message into TibjmsTextMessage", exception);
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("[CRM_EVENT] Message not read because the queue is not active");
        }

    }

}

The issue I have is if there is a switch/fail over from one EMS server to the second during the runtime then my listener fail. I would expect that the JMS reconnect out of the box to the secondary server but that it's not the case. It loops over and over on the server that is off. The only way I found to stop the retry loop is by using
FixedBackOff.
Do you know how to configure Spring & Tibco JMS to switch automatically from one server to another one during a 'disaster recovery'?
I tried multiple EMS/queue configurations, creating my own custom FixedBackOff class to live reload the JMS listener on the second server, but none of my tentative solutions worked.

How is this being used? This is a private method, so not a bean. It must be injected into something. Please show the full configuration not just snippets.

@M.Deinum I apologise for not providing enough information. I've edited my question and pasted the complete code. If my question is still incomplete, please don't hesitate to ask me for more information.

I would assume the listener container would try to re-obtain a fresh connection. Could you enable debug logging for org.springframework.jms and see what is happening there? The backoff will slow down the refresh, but there is also a default.

. Add the following properties in the EMS server configuration to make sure client applications can detect the loss of connectivity to the EMS server:
client_heartbeat_server = 20
server_timeout_client_connection = 90
server_heartbeat_client = 20
client_timeout_server_connection = 90
. Update the following property in the EMS server configuration to give time for client applications to reconnect
ft_reconnect_timeout=300
(With the above client have 5 minutes to reconnect, once this delay is expired client applications will have to open a new connection)

To understand the exact configuration used by your application and its behavior after the loss of the connectivity to the EMS server you may enable client traces at EMS server level.
Once done you will get debug messages in the stdout of your application. This can be done for all client applications with tibemsadmin using the following command:
set server client_trace enabled
You can specify a given client by adding its client id like this:
set server client_trace enabled clientid=XXXXX
From the elements you provided I can suggest to try the following:

Add reconnection parameters to your factory with the following methods (this is missing in your code)
connectionFactory.setReconnAttemptCount​(10) connectionFactory.setReconnAttemptDelay​(10000)  connectionFactory.setReconnAttemptTimeout​(1000) 


(note that with the above it will retry 10 times every 10 seconds)

Add the following properties in the EMS server configuration to make sure client applications can detect the loss of connectivity to the EMS server:

client_heartbeat_server = 20                                           server_timeout_client_connection = 90                                     server_heartbeat_client = 20                                                                                       client_timeout_server_connection = 90

Update the following property in the EMS server configuration to give time for client applications to reconnect

ft_reconnect_timeout=300
(With the above client have 5 minutes to reconnect once the new EMS server is active, once this delay is expired client applications will have to open a new connection)
